# Form Values not getting submitted

Tags: php, html, forms

I have the following PHP Code

```
<form action="admin.php" method="post">

    <?php
    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","vravi","mrconnect");
    if(!$conn)
    {
        echo "error establishing the connection";
    }
    $sql="select UserID,UserEmail from Users order by UserID";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
       {

          echo $row["UserID"];
          echo  $row["UserEmail"]." ".'<input type=\"text\" name=\"name[]\"/>'."</br>";     
        }
        echo '<button type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\"   value=\"submit\">'.Submit.'</button></br>';
    }
    ?>
</form>
```

which gives the following output in the browser.[image]

Now I have two questions.

1)When I try insert some values in one of the textboxes and click submit button in the bottom, The values are not getting submitted.

below is my admin.php php file.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo "submitted";
}
else
{
    echo "not submitted";
}


?>
```

2)Now the second question is that, I also want my email id to get submitted through the form, but it is just a normal text, can anyone tell me how do we do that?

Comment: @Rizier123 A `button` is fine, as long as the `type` is `submit`.

Comment: I think the escape string makes the problem for submit button ,

Comment: add a name attribute to your `<input>` and by using an array, you could use the email id as the key - `'<input type="text" name="name['.$row["UserID"].']">';` then in php you can do `foreach($_POST['name'] as $UserID => $value)`

Comment: @Sean: there is a `name` attribute, it just has a lot of whitespace before it :)

Comment: @LinkinTED good catch. never thought that you would need to scroll that far just to see the rest of an input

Comment: @Sean I even tried    echo  $row["UserEmail"]." ".'<input type=\"text\" name=\"name[]\">'."</br>";   but its not working and for (2) It is not a input, it is just an email id which I want to access in the "admin.php" file, I want to know how do we that.

Comment: have you tried changing `name=\"name[]\"` to `name=\"name['.$row["UserEmail"].']\"`? Also, why are you escaping all your double quotes, when you are wrapping with single quotes?

Comment: Are the `email id`s real?? :) if so i think you should use some demo emails instead of them.

Comment: could you please post your printed HTML to your question?, that will be much easier to find the issue (please [beautify](http://jsbeautifier.org/) it first)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that could change:

1. You don't need to escape double quotes when they are between single quotes
2. Use `name="name['.$row["UserID"].']"`
3. <strike>Change the `<button...` to `<input type="submit"...`</strike>

Your page will then look like this:

```
<form action="admin.php" method="post">
    <?php
    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","vravi","mrconnect");
    if(!$conn) { echo "error establishing the connection"; }

    $sql="select UserID,UserEmail from Users order by UserID";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo $row["UserID"] . ' ' . $row["UserEmail"] ." ";
            echo '<input type="text" name="name['.$row["UserID"].']" />'."<br />";
        }
        echo '<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button></br>';
    }
    ?>
</form>
```

Then, when the form is submitted to admin.php, you can loop the `name`.

```
<?php
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
    foreach( $_POST['name'] as $data => $value ) {
        echo $data . ': ' . $value . '<br />';
        // will output    2:  12
    }
}
?>
```

In my example it will echo the user id and the submitted value. You could ofcourse also save it to a database.

Comment: a button with the type of submit will also submit the form, no need to change that.

Comment: @Fadey, [you are right](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type). I didn't know that, and will update my answer. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Add `print_r();` to the top of your script to see exactly what is being posted to your page.

Correct your `input` syntax - it is incomplete:

```
echo  $row["UserEmail"]." ".'<input type=\"text\"
```

should be something like:

```
echo  $row["UserEmail"]." ".'<input type=\"text\" name=\"userEmail".$row["UserID"]."\" />
```

or even better:

```
echo  '<label>'.$row["UserEmail"].'</label><input type="text" name="userEmail['.$row["UserID"].']" />';
```

Comment: Look to the right of OP's code: `name=\"name[]\"/>'."</br>"; `

Comment: it would be easier to access in php if you did an array for the name `name=\"userEmail[".$row["UserID"]."]\"` instead of concencating the `UserID` to the end of `userEmail`

Comment: you are still concentcating. you need brackets `[ ]` around `$row["UserID"]` -> `name="userEmail['.$row["UserID"].']"`